# Is it C++ standard to set a whole array to NULL on this initializer method?

Tags: c++, arrays, standards

```
class Foo {};

int main()
{
   Foo *foo[500] = { NULL}; 
}
```

Regardless of O.S/compiler is it standard that the whole array will be set to `NULL`?

Comment: My recollection of the standard was that any array declared but not initialized has contents that are undefined. Whenever initializers are given, any uninitialized elements are automatically set to 0. So, in your example, the programmer sets the first element to NULL(0) and the compiler sets the rest of them to 0 (NULL).

Comment: Please note, that the rest of elements are set to binary '0', i.e. if you use `{ (Foo*)1 }` initializer, then only the first element will point to `(Foo*)1`, the rest is still will be pointing to `(Foo*)0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is valid and guaranteed by the C++ Standard.

**Reference:**

**C++03 Standard 8.5.1 Aggregates**
**Para 7:**

> If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be **value-initialized** (8.5). 
>   [Example:
>
> ```
>  struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
>  S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes `ss.a` with `1`, `ss.b` with `"asdf"`, and `ss.c` with the value of an expression of the form `int()`, that is,`0`. ]

Value Initialization is defined under:

**C++03 8.5 Initializers**
**Para 5:**

> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible 
>     default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static 
>     data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Comment: Props for finding the info in the actual standard.

Comment: Guaranteed, eh? So you get your money back if it doesn't work? Or are additional damages awarded too? ;)

Comment: @Kaz: The C++ standard mandates and governs behaviors on to compiler implementations.So Yes the standard guarantees the behavior but an ill-formed compiler implementation may/may not do so, and if so feel free to call the compiler rubbish and non standard compliant.

Comment: I see, so the "guarantee" gives you the remedy that you can jump up and down and curse the broken compiler. Do some consumer advocate groups know about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the construct with a single `{NULL}` where you would have expected to see 500 `NULL`s, yes, that is valid.

(Personally I make it a habit to end such lists with a comma `{NULL,}` to make it obvious that there are more implicit values, but that's just a matter of style.)

Comment: Yes, me too, just avoiding unecessary S.O pseudo-masters critiques hehe

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary , that you set it to NULL
If you wont the array will be having garbage values

Answer (score 0):

"Plain old C" structures and aggregates which are initialized are fully initialized. That comes from C. The members which do not have an initializer are initialized to zero. (Whatever zero means for their type: null pointer, or 0.0 floating-point value).

In C++, the members can be of class type with constructors.  Such members which have no initializer are initialized by their default constructors.